# SyntaxError: Failed to execute 'evaluate' on 'Document':

Tags: selenium, xpath, selenium-webdriver, automation

Can anyone please tell me, if there is any mistake with my xpath. I have made it dynamic, to accept values from the parameter passed.

**Xpath used in my code as :**

```
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.presenceOfAllElementsLocatedBy(By.xpath("//div[@id='categories_block_left']/div[1]/ul[1]/li/a[contains(text(),'"+subCategory+"')]/Preceding-sibling::span[1]")));
```

**Xpath I am getting on run time in the console after execution:**

```
//div[@id='categories_block_left']/div[1]/ul[1]/li/a[contains(text(),'Tops')]/Preceding-sibling::span[1]
```

If I try to inspect above(runtime) by mentioning `xpath` in Firpath console, it is getting detected. But selenium is not able to detect this element.

Here is page URL:

```
http://automationpractice.com/index.php?id_category=3&controller=category
```

In the eclipse console I am getting error as :

```
Expected condition failed: waiting for presence of any elements located by By.xpath: //div[@id='categories_block_left']/div[1]/ul[1]/li/a[contains(text(),'Tops')]/Preceding-sibling::span[1]
SyntaxError: Failed to execute 'evaluate' on 'Document':
```

Comment: Try `preceding-sibling` instead of `Preceding-sibling`

Comment: Yes, that is your issue, Firepath may be correcting it or selenium driver may not be liking it. So in any case you should be using `//div[@id='categories_block_left']/div[1]/ul[1]/li/a[contains(text(),'Tops')]/preceding-sibling::span[1]`

Comment: @Andersson: you are awesome! Thanks :)

Comment: @TarunLalwani: Thanks !

Comment: Xpath=//*[@type='submit']//preceding::input use like this